# Concat String to Int in sql server.- But getting error

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I'm trying to retrieve data by this, It works.

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),BH.Doc_Date,(120))AS Doc_Date
,LGH.Node_Code
,LGH.Node_Name AS Location_Name
,GD.Nationality
,GD.Guest_Name
,DBOGD.Name AS Gender
,CAST(DATEDIFF(yy,GD.Birth_Day,getdate()) AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ' yrs' AS Age
,'++' + CAST(GD.Mobile AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Mobile
,GD.NIC_No
,GD.Language
FROM [booking].[Guest_Details] AS GD ...
```

But when I'm trying to do like this,

```
SET @query = 'SELECT 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10)
                ,BH.Doc_Date,(120))AS Doc_Date
                ,LGH.Node_Code
                ,LGH.Node_Name AS Location_Name
                ,GD.Nationality
                ,GD.Guest_Name
                ,DBOGD.Name AS Gender
                ,(CAST(DATEDIFF(yy,GD.Birth_Day,getdate()) AS NVARCHAR(100)) + " yrs") AS Age
                ,"++" + CAST(GD.Mobile AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Mobile
                ,GD.NIC_No
                ,GD.Language
                FROM [booking].[Guest_Details] AS GD ...'
```

It's not working. I'm getting Errors like:

> Invalid column name ' yrs'.
>
> Invalid column name '++'.

Comment: why have you switched to the " speech marks rather than '?

Comment: Instead of double quotes `"`, use two single quotes `''`

Comment: I tried with single quotations also. But it didn't work.

Comment: Single quotes are used to indicate the beginning and end of a string in SQL. Double quotes are usually used to object names (e.g. column_name as "Emp Name").

Comment: Watch out for (and read up on) sql injection. Check out the quoteidentifier and similar functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, hope this helps you.

```
SET @query = 'SELECT 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10)
                ,BH.Doc_Date,(120))AS Doc_Date
                ,LGH.Node_Code
                ,LGH.Node_Name AS Location_Name
                ,GD.Nationality
                ,GD.Guest_Name
                ,DBOGD.Name AS Gender
                ,(CAST(DATEDIFF(yy,GD.Birth_Day,getdate()) AS NVARCHAR(100)) + '' yrs'') AS Age
                ,''++'' + CAST(GD.Mobile AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Mobile
                ,GD.NIC_No
                ,GD.Language
                FROM [booking].[Guest_Details] AS GD ...'
```

Comment: That works. Can u explain me about that. Better ' '   ' ' than " " . Btw Thank you very much.

Comment: In SQL Server the Double Quotes are just consider as a String value, But Single Quotes are used to Hold the String values. That's the problem in your Code.

Comment: @DineshDB: In SQL Server the Double Quotes are just consider as a String value ..? this is not correct

Comment: @TheGameIsWar: Single quotes are used to indicate the beginning and end of a string in SQL. Double quotes are usually used to object names (e.g. column_name as "Emp Name").

Comment: Hope my next comment is Correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yrs  part is causing you issue..Modify it like below

```
   ,DBOGD.Name AS Gender
                ,(CAST(DATEDIFF(yy,GD.Birth_Day,getdate()) AS NVARCHAR(100)) + '' yrs'') AS Age
                ,CAST(GD.Mobile AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Mobile
                ,GD.NIC_No
                ,GD.Language
                FROM [booking].[Guest_Details] AS GD ...'
```

Comment: That works. Can u explain me about that. Better ' '   ' ' than " " . Btw Thank you very much.

Comment: @TKrish: your are tyring to use strings like in c#.in sql you have set strings with single quote and there was a redundant ++.always print your SQL so that you can catch errors yourself

Answer (score 1):

Instead of double quotes `"`, use two single quotes `''` in these places `" yrs"`, `"++"`.

```
SET @query = 
    'SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), BH.Doc_Date,(120)) AS Doc_Date
    ,LGH.Node_Code
    ,LGH.Node_Name AS Location_Name
    ,GD.Nationality
    ,GD.Guest_Name
    ,DBOGD.Name AS Gender
    ,(CAST(DATEDIFF(yy, GD.Birth_Day,getdate()) AS NVARCHAR(100)) + '' yrs'') AS Age -- in this line
    ,''++'' + CAST(GD.Mobile AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Mobile -- and in this line
    ,GD.NIC_No
    ,GD.Language
    FROM [booking].[Guest_Details] AS GD ...'
```

Comment: That works. Can u explain me about that. Better ' '   ' ' than " " . Btw Thank you very much.